# Git-Flow en diferentes máquina

Tags: git

Estoy usando git-flow para mi proyecto en dos equipos y quisiera saber qué puedo hacer cuando cierro una rama (*branch*). Pongo como ejemplo del flujo de trabajo la siguiente situación:

Creo en el *Equipo A* la rama `feature/politica` y cuando llego al *Equipo B* hago `git pull origin feature/politica` y `git checkout -b feature/politica` para trabajar en esa rama.

Ahora finalizo la rama en el *Equipo B* (usando [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)) lo que hace un *merge* de la rama `feature/politica` con la rama `develop` y **borra la rama *local* `feature/politica`**.

¿Debo ignorar y borrar la rama `feature/politica` local original en el *Eqipo A* y simplemente traer la rama `develop`? ¿Es correcto el flujo de control de código tal como lo planteo?

Comment: Si ya no necesitas la rama, o sea, si ya está completo ese feature, puedes borrarla, creo que no existe solución correcta o incorrecta aquí, todo es válido, depende de tu proyecto.

Comment: Deja la rama que ya no vas a usar, no es necesario que la elimines. Si en algún momento te toca regresar a alguna versión anterior incluso podría servirte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¿Porque eliminas la rama *feature/politica*? Es una rama que nunca más vas a tener que evolucionar o corregir, entonces podría ser correcto borrarla. Si sabes que vas a tener que modificarla en otro momento o que cambiara en diferentes versiones puede que no sea la mejor idea.

Es correcto o no en función de lo que necesites, en mi opinión si *feature* no va a ser evolucionada o modificada se puede eliminar sin más, si por el contrario se sabe claramente que con el tiempo cambiara o que va ser evolucionada pues creo que es más adecuado mantenerla aun despues del *merge*.

En el proyecto en el que estoy tenemos una rama *versión/integration* por cada version que mantenemos, de esta cuelga inmediatamente otra llamada *version/development* y de esta siempre cuelgan las ramas *ID_xxxx* que corresponden a cada tarea de la versión, estas siempre se mergean sobre *version/development* de tal forma que sabes todas las tareas que se han realizado para una versión, incluso si una tarea no se incluye en una version se puede mergear a otra version pero siempre *version/development*.

Por ultimo, las ramas *version/development* se mergean sobre *version/integration* creando version cerrada y etiquetada, esto nos permite tener diferentes versiones vivas, y poder pasar tareas de una versión a otra si es necesario como en el caso de los FIX. Por ejemplo, detectamos un FIX en la versión 1.7.4, creamos una tarea para solventarla y la mergeamos para crear la versión 1.7.5 y ademas también la mergeamos a la versión 1.8.1 y 2.0.3.

Espero que te aclare algo tus dudas